# OpenTelemetry dotnet otel configuration

Tags: open-telemetry

I'm writing simple project for study OpenTelemetry.

I want to use otel for configure many exporter.

[Sample](https://github.com/andreatosato/OpenTelemetrySql/blob/3845a7d70d508bd8fbf00d11631f576f3b28bdf1/src/docker-compose.yml#L29-L61)

Can anyone suggest me how can I must configure agent and collector?
I tried github sample but don't work properly.

My docker-compose:

```
otel-collector:
container_name: otel-collector
image: otel/opentelemetry-collector
volumes:
  - ./../config/otel-collector-config.yaml:/etc/otel-collector-config.yaml
ports:
  - "1888:1888"   # pprof extension
  - "8888:8888"   # Prometheus metrics exposed by the collector
  - "8889:8889"   # Prometheus exporter metrics
  - "13133:13133" # health_check extension
  - "4317"        # OTLP gRPC receiver
  - "55670:55679" # zpages extension
depends_on:
  - zipkin
 

otel-agent:
    container_name: otel-agent
    image: otel/opentelemetry-collector
    command: ["--config=/etc/otel-agent-config.yaml", "${OTELCOL_ARGS}"]
    volumes:
      - ./../config/otel-agent-config.yaml:/etc/otel-agent-config.yaml
    ports:
      - "8887:8888"   # Prometheus metrics exposed by the agent
      - "14250"       # Jaeger grpc receiver
      - "14268"       # Jaeger http thrift receiver
      - "55678"       # OpenCensus receiver
      - "4317"        # OTLP gRPC receiver
      - "9411"        # Zipkin receiver
      - "1777:1777"   # pprof extension
      - "55679:55679" # zpages extension
      - "13133"       # health_check
    depends_on:
      - otel-collector
```

My Agent config:

I want to receive data from .net application and redirect it to otel-collector.

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
      http:
  zipkin:

exporters:
  otlp:
    endpoint: otel-collector:4317
    insecure: true
  logging:
    loglevel: debug

processors:
  batch:

extensions:
  health_check:
  pprof:
    endpoint: 0.0.0.0:1777
  zpages:
    endpoint: 0.0.0.0:55679

service:
  extensions: [health_check, pprof, zpages]
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp, zipkin]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [otlp, logging]
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [otlp, logging]
```

My collector config:

I want to receive data from agent and redirect to exporter:
zipkin, newrelic, logger.

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
      http:

exporters:
  logging:
    loglevel: debug

  zipkin:
    endpoint: "http://zipkin:9411/api/v2/spans"
    format: proto

  newrelic:
    apikey: NRAK-abc
    timeout: 30s
    traces:
      host_override: trace-api.eu.newrelic.com
      timeout: 20s
    metrics:
      host_override: metric-api.eu.newrelic.com
    logs:
      host_override: log-api.eu.newrelic.com

processors:
  batch:

extensions:
  health_check:
  pprof:
    endpoint: :1888
  zpages:
    endpoint: :55679

service:
  extensions: [pprof, zpages, health_check]
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [logging, zipkin, newrelic]
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [logging, zipkin, newrelic]
```

My dotnet application startup:

```
services.AddOpenTelemetryTracing((builder) => builder
                    .AddSource("Sample")
                    .SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault().AddService("SampleApi").AddTelemetrySdk())
                    .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation(options =>
                    {
                        options.Filter = (req) => !req.Request.Path.ToUriComponent().Contains("swagger", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                    })
                    .AddOtlpExporter(otlpOptions =>
                    {
                        otlpOptions.Endpoint = new Uri("http://otel-collector:4317");
                    })
```